# Kendo UI line chart sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

I can't work out how to get the categories ordering correctly on the x-axis in a kendo UI line chart. Here's my example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script src="js/thirdParty/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/thirdParty/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var data,
            dataSource;
        data = [{
                type: "C1",
                amount: 100,
                year: 2008
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2008
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2009
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 10,
                year: 2010
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2011
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2011
            }];
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: data,
            group: {field: "type"},
                sort: { field: "year" }
        });
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                series: [{
                    type: "line",
                    field: "amount",
                    categoryField: "year",
                    name: "#= group.value #"
                }],
            })
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's a screen shot of what the output looks like:

[image]

As you can see the years are ordered incorrectly even though the data is in year order and I've specified to sort on year in the kendo data source.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the years from a Number to date, e.g:

```
data = [{
           type: "C1",
               amount: 100,
               year: new Date(2008, 0, 1);
           }, {
               type: "C2",
               amount: 120,
               year: new Date(2009, 0, 1)
           }, ... // etc.
```

You can then even further define `baseUnitStep` steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a data bound to your chart like this:

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var data,
            dataSource;
        data = [{
                type: "C1",
                amount: 100,
                year: 2008
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2008
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2009
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 10,
                year: 2010
            }, {
                type: "C1",
                amount: 120,
                year: 2011
            }, {
                type: "C2",
                amount: 50,
                year: 2011
            }];
        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: data,
            group: {field: "type"},
                sort: { field: "year" }
        });
            $("#chart").kendoChart({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                series: [{
                    type: "line",
                    field: "amount",
                    categoryField: "year",
                    name: "#= group.value #"
                }],
              dataBound: function(e) {
          var axis = e.sender.options.categoryAxis;
          axis.categories = axis.categories.sort();
        }
            })
        });
    </script>
```